# Slow Upload in PHP joomla controler

Tags: php, apache, joomla

here is the code that i use to upload files and unzip them in a directory.
But the problem is that it seems to be very slow on files greater than 5MB.
I think it doesnt have to do with the network because it is in localhost computer.
Do I need to edit any parameter in php.ini file or apache or any other workarround?

```
$target_path = "../somepath/";
            $target_path .= JRequest::getVar('uploadedDirectory')."/";  

            $target_Main_path= JRequest::getVar('uploadedDirectory')."/";

            $folderName = $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'];      
            $target_path = $target_path . basename($folderName);

            //upload file
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path."/")) {
                echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded";
            } else{
                echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
            }


            $zip = new ZipArchive;
        $res = $zip->open($target_path);


            $target_path = str_replace(".zip", "", $target_path);

            echo $target_path;

     if ($res === TRUE) {
         $zip->extractTo($target_path."/");
         $zip->close();
         echo "ok";
     } else {
         echo "failed";
     }
```

Comment: it seems that the problem is not with joomla but in php. I created a simple file with the above code and I used it to upload a file with size 5MB, but it takes ages and it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When handling file uploads ther are a lot of factors to consider. These include PHP settings:

- max_input_time
- max_execution_time
- upload_max_filesize
- post_max_size

Execution time can affect the upload if for example, you have a slow upload speed resulting in a timeout.

File size can cause problems if the upload is larger than the `upload_max_filesize` like wise if your file size + the rest of the post data exceeds `post_max_size`.

Zip uses a lot of memory in the archive/extraction processes and could easily exceed the memory allocated to PHP -so that would be worth checking as well.

I would start with [this](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) page and note some of the comments.

Comment: thanx for your answer, but nothing helped. I have 
max_input_time = 60
max_execution_time = 30
upload_max_filesize = 110M
post_max_size = 8MB

The file i am trying to upload is like 574KB (the last test I made).
Also I created a testproject in apache root alown in order to test the upload functionality of php, but it is still slow. It seems that it has to do with some setting on apache or php. Still cant address the problem

Comment: same code on my unix server where I am hosting the file seems to be working fine and fast. Its on my Windows machine were i encounter the problem.

Comment: well I am surprised, I tested with Google Chrome and I looked at the bottom there is a progress % that is occurring when I start to upload and with chrome everything looks to work fine. The problem occurs when Firefox is uploading. Therefor I must accept your answer since It was helpfull. Thanx